# validation and training don't converge at the same time, but validation still converges

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, object-detection, resnet

https://github.com/wenxinxu/resnet-in-tensorflow#overall-structure

The link above is the Resnet model for cifar10.

I am modifying above code to do object detection using Resnet and Cifar10 as training/validating dataset. ( I know the dataset is for object classification) I know that it sounds strange, but hear me out. I use Cifar10 for training and validation then during testing I use a sliding window approach, and then I classify each of the windows to one of 10 classes + "background" classes.

for background classes, I used images from ImageNet. I search ImageNet with following keyword: construction, landscape, byway, mountain, sky, ocean, furniture, forest, room, store, carpet, and floor. then I clean bad images out as much as I can including images that contain Cifar10 classes, for example, I delete a few "floor" images that have dogs in it.

I am currently running the result in Floydhub. Total steps that I am running is 60,000 which is where section under "training curve" from the link about suggests that the result starts to consolidate and do not converge further ( I personally run this code myself and I can back up the claim)

My question is:

1. what is the cause of the sudden step down in training and validation data which occurs at about the same step?
2. What if(or Is it possible that)training and validation data don't converge in a step-like fashion at about the same step? what I mean is, for example, training steps down at around 40,000 and validation just converge with no step-down? (smoothly converge)

Answer (score 1):

1. The sudden step down is caused by the learning rate decay happening at 40k steps (you can find this parameter in *hyper_parameters.py*). The leraning rate suddenly gets divided by 10, which allows you to tune the parameters more precisely, which in this case improves your performance a lot. You still need the first part, with a pretty big learning rate, to get in a "good" area for your parameters, then the part with a 10x smaller learning rate will refine it and find a very good spot in that area for your parameters.
2. This would be surprising, since there is a clear difference between before and after 40k, that affects training and validation the same way. You could still see different behaviors from that point: for instance you might start overtraining because of a too small LR, and see you train error drop down and validation go up, because the refinements you're doing are too specific to the training data.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is actually the first time I used learning rate decay.